# Animate from zero height to dynamic destination height in fixed time with react native

Tags: react-native-web

This question differs from some similar question in that I want to go from 0 to the height that would be determined by nativeEvent.layout.height - if it wasn't being animated - in duration of say 500ms.

This works on web. On iOS device it gets a smaller than final height from the layout event because the animation is not completed

Right now I'm getting the destination height from the native Event layout and running the animation to the layout height as soon as that happens, this causes multiple animations to occur which brings about the intended height but no longer in 500ms, more like a few seconds.

```
Animated.timing(
          cardHeight[index],
          {
            toValue: newHeight,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: false
          }
        ),
```

What I'd like to do is use something like scrollHeight or innerHeight of the element which remains the same regardless of what actual height it is but this obviously isn't available on device.

Answer (score 0):

My answer was to put the content whose height to measure using the layout event within a scroll view and then taking the event on the scroll views contents.